# Nuevo data frame a partir de columnas determinadas de mi data frame original

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Tengo un data frame con 34 variables (`datosNum`) y quiero crear un data frame nuevo aparte (`datosNumSubgrupo`) que contenga variables determinadas de datosNum, sin nigún tipo de filtrado o criterio especial, sino variables que yo quiero que esten incluidas en el nuevo data frame a 'dedo' y que conserven su forma (osea, que el nuevo data frame tenga esas mismas columnas, separadas, como en el data frame original, con el mismo numero de filas que el data frame original)

Si quiero que, por ejemplo, mi nuevo data frame contenga las variables `datosNum$MS`, `datosNum$Frontage` y `datosNum$LowQual` qué debería hacer? Para que luego, a la hora de hacer boxplots, los pueda hacer por subgrupos (los nuevos dataframes) y mostrarlos en un mismo gráfico:

`par(mfrow=c(1,1))` `boxplot(datosNumSubgrupo)`

**** Si, que el nuevo data frame conserve el mismo número de observaciones/filas. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Quizá sea esto lo que buscas:

```r
library(dplyr)
datosNumSubgrupo <- datos %>% select(MS, Frontage, LowQual)

head(datosNumSubgrupo)
```

Comment: ¿Quizás? Si no estás seguro, mejor colocalo como comentario.